# Access Secured "HTTPS" webservice - WP 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to access the secured "HTTPS" webservice in Windows Phone 7. The secured certificate is not given, I should  either skip or ignore the error message. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The site you're accessing needs to have a valid certificate from an issuer recognised by the platform. The latest list of these issuers I've seen is here.

[push notifications from authenticated services](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/62133.aspx)

Note Geotrust will give you a 30 day trial certificate which is handy for testing.

Comment: The thing is I will not be given any certificate, all I should do is to bypass the error message

Comment: There's no option to do that at the moment. If you're not in control of the service, and the service doesn't issue a trusted certificate, you're out of options at the moment. You could comment on the suggestions forum or on Connect (vs/wpdt) if it's important.